# Does Armor reduce damage to the Energy Shield?

Tags: path-of-exile

If I have

- 50% damage reduction due to my armor
- 100 energy shield up
- Monster attack for 150 physical damage

What will happen?

Does it deal (150*0.5) damage to my energy shield?

or

Will it crush my energy shield and hit me with (150-100)*0.5 damage?

Comment: Interesting question.  I play a pure ES gear character, so I can't test.

Comment: @fbueckert That's exactly what I wanne build, a pure ES char: http://www.pathofexile.com/passive-skill-tree/AAAAAgMBAW8HYw5IEHsRLREvEVARlhHbFkAc3B0UHdkfAilPKwospjN2NAo3ZjeDOBs62DvhPI5DVENjRwZMNU3YT79XK1fJWPVfamaebRlxTXWKfIN_xoFvg_eESIV9hcWIa4t6jHaOvo9Gj_qRz5I4ksGTJ5mams-dxJ48oqOm66cIpyu0xbb3tzG4k7vWvjrBAMHFwfPC7MNtzfrUBdsa2-fesN-w4vfjguOE5BHmfOaB5wvquutj6-7sGOw49Uv3wfrS

Comment: @StephanSchielke if you are building a pure ES character then you wont have any armor.

Comment: @StephanSchielke I am fairly positive that armor will reduce the amount of damage taken before it hits your Energy shield though. All of my characters I have made so far were built with Armor and Energy Shield gear(usually chainmail/ringmail, stuff like that). I have no evidence of this though so I won't put it as an answer.

Comment: It wouldn't make much logical sense for armor to effect ES, but that doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't.

Comment: @Ravekner I am playing hardcore. From lvl 1-75 I wont have the perfect equipment! I need to know when to skill and when to do what...

Comment: In all honesty though, I think this question may be unanswerable, I don't remember if this is correct or not, but I'm pretty sure there is no damage taken/damage dealt numbers that come up on the screen when you are fighting monsters

Comment: @Ravekner of course you can test it! Just take an armor flask with 4000 armor and observe. Unfortenatly I can't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Armour is applied to physical damage before it reaches your Life or Energy Shield.

Here is [a quote](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/38125/page/2#p519893) from one of the game developers, Mark_GGG:

> 1) Avoiding the hit:
>   - Chance to hit (accuracy vs evasion) for attacks
>   - Chance to dodge for attacks, or spells with phase acrobatics
>
> 2) Avoiding the damage:
>       - Block chance for attacks, sometimes spells.
>
> 3) Mitigating the damage:
>   - Armour for physical damage.
>   - Resistances for non-physical damage.
>
> 4) Taking the damage:
>   - Non-chaos damage removed from energy shield until it's depleted.
>   - Remaining damage (including all chaos) removed from life.

Also FYI, armour does **not** reduce a certain percentage of *all* attacks. The amount it reduces is dependent upon the damage dealt. In order to get a 50% reduction of a 150 damaging attack you would need 1,800 Armour Rating. 1,800 Armour Rating would reduce a 300 damage attack by 33% and a 600 damage attack by 20%.

Comment: Thanks. That's really all you need. First mitigating then taking damage.

Comment: That comment by the developer didn't answer the question. They say armor reduces physical and resistance reduces elemental but that does not state whether or not those reductions are applied to ES as well as health. Again, non-chaos damage being removed from ES first doesn't mean that armour bonuses and resistances apply...

Comment: @DexterWalters The steps are sequential and are applied in the order listed.